# Extracting Require information from google map place api in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am working on GPS app in which i need to determine location based on longitude and Latitude of a place.I am able to determine the longitude and latitude and also location but i am getting the result of the google maps api call in json format in which there is a lot of data along with city name.

I have done like this.(I am using simulator so i have passed fixed latitude and longitude)

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",30.819297, 76.444017];
    NSError* error;
        NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        locationString = [locationString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@",locationString );
```

The output string i am getting is

015-04-16 10:38:45.056 demolocationapp[690:12005] {

```
   results : [
      {
         address_components : [
            {
               long_name : Rauni Kalan Link Road,
               short_name : Rauni Kalan Link Rd,
               types : [ route ]
            },
            {
             **long_name : Rauni Kalan,
               short_name : Rauni Kalan,
               types : [ locality, political]**

            },
            {
               long_name : Rupnagar,
               short_name : Rupnagar,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_2, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : Punjab,
               short_name : PB,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_1, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : India,
               short_name : IN,
               types : [ country, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : 140102,
               short_name : 140102,
               types : [ postal_code ]
            }
         ],
         formatted_address : Rauni Kalan Link Road, Rauni Kalan, Punjab 140102, India,
         geometry : {
            bounds : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.8209903,
                  lng : 76.4550081
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.8178417,
                  lng : 76.44540219999999
               }
            },
            location : {
               lat : 30.8186057,
               lng : 76.4507395
            },
            location_type : APPROXIMATE,
            viewport : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.8209903,
                  lng : 76.4550081
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.8178417,
                  lng : 76.44540219999999
               }
            }
         },
         place_id : ChIJc8IoHwICEDkR38Ie5TOeGu0,
         types : [ route ]
      },
      {
         address_components : [
            {
               long_name : Rauni Kalan,
               short_name : Rauni Kalan,
               types : [ locality, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : Rupnagar,
               short_name : Rupnagar,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_2, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : Punjab,
               short_name : PB,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_1, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : India,
               short_name : IN,
               types : [ country, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : 140102,
               short_name : 140102,
               types : [ postal_code ]
            }
         ],
         formatted_address : Rauni Kalan, Punjab 140102, India,
         geometry : {
            bounds : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.8219531,
                  lng : 76.4462614
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.81705139999999,
                  lng : 76.4414979
               }
            },
            location : {
               lat : 30.8192965,
               lng : 76.44401660000001
            },
            location_type : APPROXIMATE,
            viewport : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.8219531,
                  lng : 76.4462614
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.81705139999999,
                  lng : 76.4414979
               }
            }
         },
         place_id : ChIJ_f1PWh0CEDkRKlzFwhc62zo,
         types : [ locality, political ]
      },
      {
         address_components : [
            {
               long_name : 140102,
               short_name : 140102,
               types : [ postal_code ]
            },
            {
               long_name : Punjab,
               short_name : PB,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_1, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : India,
               short_name : IN,
               types : [ country, political ]
            }
         ],
         formatted_address : Punjab 140102, India,
         geometry : {
            bounds : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.869706,
                  lng : 76.47508049999999
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.7970006,
                  lng : 76.3335855
               }
            },
            location : {
               lat : 30.8288892,
               lng : 76.4215988
            },
            location_type : APPROXIMATE,
            viewport : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.869706,
                  lng : 76.47508049999999
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.7970006,
                  lng : 76.3335855
               }
            }
         },
         place_id : ChIJHX2_rA0BEDkR_QslHcc_M0g,
         types : [ postal_code ]
      },
      {
         address_components : [
            {
               long_name : Fatehgarh Sahib,
               short_name : Fatehgarh Sahib,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_2, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : Punjab,
               short_name : PB,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_1, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : India,
               short_name : IN,
               types : [ country, political ]
            }
         ],
         formatted_address : Fatehgarh Sahib, Punjab, India,
         geometry : {
            bounds : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.8779699,
                  lng : 76.63427999999999
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.4275501,
                  lng : 76.0761799
               }
            },
            location : {
               lat : 30.6810924,
               lng : 76.4100267
            },
            location_type : APPROXIMATE,
            viewport : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 30.8779699,
                  lng : 76.63427999999999
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 30.4275501,
                  lng : 76.0761799
               }
            }
         },
         place_id : ChIJqf6CHWocEDkR4EljDGd5be8,
         types : [ administrative_area_level_2, political ]
      },
      {
         address_components : [
            {
               long_name : Punjab,
               short_name : PB,
               types : [ administrative_area_level_1, political ]
            },
            {
               long_name : India,
               short_name : IN,
               types : [ country, political ]
            }
         ],
         formatted_address : Punjab, India,
         geometry : {
            bounds : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 32.4981352,
                  lng : 76.92175809999999
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 29.537147,
                  lng : 73.8708879
               }
            },
            location : {
               lat : 31.1471305,
               lng : 75.34121789999999
            },
            location_type : APPROXIMATE,
            viewport : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 32.4981352,
                  lng : 76.92175809999999
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 29.537147,
                  lng : 73.8708879
               }
            }
         },
         place_id : ChIJVXOeVqpkGTkRYYijAzEmvY8,
         types : [ administrative_area_level_1, political ]
      },
      {
         address_components : [
            {
               long_name : India,
               short_name : IN,
               types : [ country, political ]
            }
         ],
         formatted_address : India,
         geometry : {
            bounds : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 35.5087008,
                  lng : 97.395561
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 6.7535159,
                  lng : 68.162386
               }
            },
            location : {
               lat : 20.593684,
               lng : 78.96288
            },
            location_type : APPROXIMATE,
            viewport : {
               northeast : {
                  lat : 35.5087008,
                  lng : 97.395561
               },
               southwest : {
                  lat : 6.7535159,
                  lng : 68.16288519999999
               }
            }
         },
         place_id : ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc,
         types : [ country, political ]
      }
   ],
   status : OK
}
```

I have put my Required data where type is locality,political in **Required Text **

How can i get that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used this method

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",30.819297, 76.444017]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

             NSArray *arr=[[json valueForKeyPath:@"results.address_components"] objectAtIndex:0];

        for (NSDictionary *dictAddress in arr)
        {
            if ([[dictAddress objectForKey:@"types"] count] > 0)
            {
                if([[[dictAddress objectForKey:@"types"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"locality"])
                {
                    return [dictAddress objectForKey:@"long_name"];
                }
                else if([[[dictAddress objectForKey:@"types"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"political"])
                {
                    return [dictAddress objectForKey:@"long_name"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return @"";
            }
        }
        return @"";
        }
    }
}];
```

Using this method you will find the name of the area which type start with "locality" or "political".

But i have took first object of the api response but if you need rathar than this , then put loop to take object of the json called.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your string of the JSON object to an NSDictionary and then use key/value accessors to get each field.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",30.819297, 76.444017]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSArray *results = [json valueForKey:@"results"];
        for (NSDictionary *result in results) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", [result valueForKey:@"formatted_address"]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [result valueForKey:@"place_id"]);
            // Etc...
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would use NSURLSessions and blocks to make network calls. The beauty of blocks is that if my network connection is poor my block will only get executed at after the call returns.

Then you need to convert your JSON to foundation objects that you can work with.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",30.819297,76.444017];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//Next we need a NSURLSession instance
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

//All tasks (there are three, see documentation) are created from an NSURLSession instance
//We want a DataTask
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //This "block" (of code) will be executed when the call is complete

    //Serialize the JSON to Foundation objects
    NSDictionary *geocodeDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    //Parse through the JSON to get to where we want, address_components array
    NSArray *resultsArray = geocodeDictionary[@"results"];
    NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = resultsArray[0];
    NSArray *addressComponents = resultsDictionary[@"address_components"];

    //Declare variables to hold desired results
    NSString *longName;
    NSString *shortName;

    //The address_components array contains many dictionaries,
    //we loop through each dictionary and check the types array
    for (NSDictionary *addressComponentDictionary in addressComponents) {
        NSArray *typesArray = addressComponentDictionary[@"types"];

        if (    [typesArray[0] isEqualToString:@"locality"]
             && [typesArray[1] isEqualToString:@"political"]) {
            //the type IS locality and political
            longName = addressComponentDictionary[@"long_name"];
            shortName = addressComponentDictionary[@"short_name"];
        }
    }

    //Test log to see we are correct
    NSLog(@"%@", longName);
    NSLog(@"%@", shortName);
}];

[dataTask resume];
```